# Return more than one month from this oracle query

Tags: database, oracle

```
select RuleDate,to_char(RuleDate,'D')DAYS 
FROM (
select add_months(last_day(sysdate),-1)+level RuleDate 
FROM dual connect by level<=to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD')
);
```

I have a task using oracle DB to return dates for a whole year rather than just a month. I have been only able to generate the above SQL so far which only generates one month.

Comment: Current calendar year? Last 12 months? If the last 12 months, from the start of the month or 365 days ago? You need to be a lot more specific in your problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query. The query will return dates for a year **after** `SYSDATE`.

```sql
WITH dt AS (
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE) curr_date 
  FROM DUAL
 )
SELECT curr_date + LEVEL dates
  FROM dt
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (curr_date, 12) - curr_date
```

If you need the dates **starting from `SYSDATE`** subtract one from the date `curr_date + LEVEL - 1`.

```
WITH dt AS (
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE) curr_date 
  FROM DUAL
 )
SELECT curr_date + LEVEL - 1 dates
  FROM dt
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (curr_date, 12) - curr_date
```

Answer (score 0):

For the whole current year? Something like this:

```
with temp (bdate, edate) as
  (select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'),
          add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12)
   from dual
  )
select bdate + level - 1 datum
from temp
connect by level <= edate - bdate
order by datum;
```

which results in

```
DATUM
----------
01.01.2021
02.01.2021
03.01.2021
04.01.2021
05.01.2021
06.01.2021
07.01.2021
<snip>
27.12.2021
28.12.2021
29.12.2021
30.12.2021
31.12.2021

365 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

For the *next* year, slightly modify `bdate` in the CTE; the rest remains *as is*.

```
with temp (bdate, edate) as
  (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12),
          add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 24)
   from dual
  )
select bdate + level - 1 datum
from temp
connect by level <= edate - bdate
order by datum

DATUM
----------
01.01.2022
02.01.2022
03.01.2022
<snip>
28.12.2022
29.12.2022
30.12.2022
31.12.2022

365 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for the solution but i need it to be 1 year after sysdate not for the current year of sysdate.

my current solution is to use UNION for each add months

Comment: For the "next year", modify BDATE in the CTE as `add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12)` (see updated answer). The rest of the query remains as is. Your current solution (UNION) probably works, but is suboptimal.